# Back button exiting application in android 

Tags: android, activitygroup

I'm a bit puzzeled, I have an application which has 5 tabs in tabHost. Each tab has an activityGroup, which further has a parent and a child activity. The parent activity contains list of titles and the child activity has the details of those titles. Now, if I move on to another tab in my application from details page and then come back to the same tab in which i was viewing the details, the details are again displayed whereas the parent activity should be shown or if i press back button from here it exits my application whereas it should go to it's parent activity.

It is like

Tab1 - ActivityGroup                                              Tab2 - ActivityGroup

```
     ParentActivity1 - ListActivity          ParentActivity2 - ListActivity

     ChildActivity1 - Activity               ChildActivity2 - Activity
```

Now when i go from ChildActivity1 to Tab2 - ParentActivity2 and come back to Tab1 i get to see the ChildActivity1 only and if i press back button then my application exits

Please help

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution for this? 
Do I have to implement back button on every single activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the back button, and bring up the activity you want. As far as the system is concerned, I think it treats your TabActivity as the only Activity to have BACK act upon.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        // goto parent screen
}
```

Comment: I have used this code in my ActivityGroup. If I move from ParentActivity1 to ChildActivity1 and then press back it moves back to the ParentActivity1 but if i move from ChildActivity1 to Tab2 and then come back to Tab1 ChildActivity1 is shown

Answer (score 2):

Seems Your stack not managed properly or  clearing up .
check what stack option you are passing with intent for new activity .

Comment: if using intetn.addflag(FLAG_NAME); then check whether it is appropriate ,should not be FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY ;